# Почему данный код нормально работает в песочнице кода, но не работает на хостинге?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть такой скрипт плавного перехода по якорям.

```
const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="#"]')

for (let anchor of anchors) {
anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

const blockID = anchor.getAttribute('href').substr(1);

document.getElementById(blockID).scrollIntoView({
  behavior: 'smooth',
  block: 'start'
})
})
}
```

Подключил его в песочнице кода к моему html файлу — все работает. Выгрузил в отдельный файл header.js и подключил к index.html на [github pages](https://konstantinshirmanov.github.io/sz1html/) переход по якорям стал стандартный, не плавный. Почему так произошло?

Comment: когда вызывается этот код у тебя еще нет элементов на странице, поэтому и обработчики не навешиваются. Либо перенеси подключение скрипта вниз страницы, либо добавь атрибут defer или async

Comment: @Grundy Перенес подключение скрипта вниз. Спасибо, все работает. А почему в песочнице работало сразу?

Comment: это надо смотреть что за песочница. Скорее всего, там скрипт автоматом подключается вниз страницы. Либо оборачивается в обработчик `onload`